# Security Exception when using ExecutorService on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm getting an exception when using the ExecutorService on Google App Engine.

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThread") at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:375)
```

My code is

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(25,com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory());        
List<Future<JSONObject>> results = service.invokeAll(jobs,45,TimeUnit.Seconds);
```

Looking it seems the Thread.interrupt is causing the security manager to trigger. The doc is a little unclear, some places say interrupt is okay, other places it says it's only available on the current thread.

I tried replicating the same thing, spawning a thread and then interrupting it, without using ExecutorService and it works fine.

Any ideas if this is a security thing I can tweak (unlikely), or a bug? I'd rather not reimplement ExecutorService.

Thanks!

Comment: Although this is 3 years old... AppEngine has it's own api for threading. Your not trusted to make your own.